# Google Books API Authors

Tags: python, get-request, google-books, google-books-api

I'm using the Google Books API and I want the api to send me back book info about a specific author (like list some of their books). However my link currently doesn't seem to be doing that as whenever I use the inauthor parameter, all the books it sends me aren't written by the author.

For example:
'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=inauthor: emilyhenry & printType=books&langRestrict=en&key=mykey'

none of the books returned with this link are written by emily henry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to factor in the space(so first name plus last name) in author's name. so it will be `emily+henry`

so api call will be:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=inauthor:emily+henry&printType=books&langRestrict=en&key=mykey
```

Answer (score 0):

When running the same request with the given url, I am also getting back books not written by the given author. However, if I remove the spaces in the url that shouldn't be there, I get back 0 books. I think your search of "emilyhenry" isn't yielding results.